I want to access my sharepoint site through webdav in android
I'm trying to have access to my sharepoint files, especially music files, through webdav in android. I have an Office 365 A1 license.
I managed to have it working with Windows (which accepts both url and \\example.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\admin). I had to generate an app password for this as I have 2FA enabled.
But I'm unable to have access at all in android, I tried multiple apps and they all give me errors, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I'm setting my webdav connection like this:
URL: https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/admin/Shared%20documents
Username: myname@domain.com
Password: apppassword

These are the apps I already tried: samba player, carta, ease music player, davx5.
I managed to get the log of a davx5 and it says that the connection gets killed when reaching this url:
https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/admin/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2Fsites%2Fadmin%2FShared%20documents

Which forces you to login through a 2FA authentication, which will never resolve, but it shouldn't do this it should just login with the app password I generated for this.
I'm lost, I'm guessing the issue lies with the url of my sharepoint site, I tried many alternatives to no avail, username is fine, password is fine, I repeat, the same settings work on windows, I even generated a different app password just in case they are for unique uses, but nothing.
